# Grid packing algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, fill

Given a rectangle of size `w` x `h`, and a requirement to fit `n` equally sized rectangles *within* that larger rectangle, pick the size `dx` and `dy` for those smaller rectangles that optimally fills the original rectangle.

The primary constraint is that all numbers *must be integers*.

My current (JS) algorithm is this:

```
function pack(n, w, h) {

    var nx, ny;
    var dx = w, dy = h;  // initally try one rectangle that fills the box

    while (true) {
        nx = ~~(w / dx); // see how many times this fits in X
        ny = ~~(h / dy); // and in Y

        if (nx * ny >= n) break;   // they all fit!

        if (dx * h >= w * dy) {    // look at the aspect ratio
            dx = ~~(w / (nx + 1)); // try fitting more horizontally
        } else {
            dy = ~~(h / (ny + 1)); // or try more vertically
        }

        if (dx < 1 || dy < 1) {
            return;                // they can't fit
        }
    };

    return [nx, ny, dx, dy];
};
```

Is there a better algorithm?

[NB: this is not homework - I'm trying to solve the problem of how to draw "n" items in a matrix on a canvas, but where each item must only use whole pixels].

Comment: This might be helpful. Its a very similar question but not quite the same. It might give you some ideas though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513081/create-an-optimal-grid-based-on-n-items-total-area-and-hw-ratio/

Comment: Also do the smaller rectangles have to be constrained by a certain height/width ratio or anything like that?

Comment: @Chris, well, they shouldn't be 1 pixel wide by 200 high, for example...

Comment: @Altinak: I was hoping for something more concrete than that. ;-) I don't know your exact use case but you might be better off not necessarily going for the optimal fitting but constrain the ratio dx/dy in some way that means you have a more aesthetically pleasing result even if it wastes one pixel compared to something that uses all the pixels but has an extreme aspect ratio...

Comment: @chris aesthetically, I'd be aiming for an aspect ratio that's "approximately" the same as that of the original grid.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're basically trying to calculate [GCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor), which you can do efficiently using the [Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Implementations).  I think the following works - try it out!

First, calculate gwn = GCD(w,n) and ghn = GCD(h,n).  If either of these is n, you're done - if gwn = n, it means each rectangle can be w/n by h pixels.  Otherwise, you can only fit the rectangles if h is divisible by n/gwn or w is divisible by n/ghn.

Comment: it sounds like you're describing an _exact_ fit, where there can be no spare pixels left over in either axis?

Comment: Alnitak: you are correct, I will have to think about the non-exact case.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function pick(tiles, grid_width, grid_height)
{
    var max_area = ~~(grid_width * grid_height / tiles);

    for (var area = max_area; area > 0; area--)
    {
        var result = [grid_width * grid_height - area * tiles];

        divisors_do(area,
            function (tile_width)
            {

                var tile_height = area / tile_width;
                if (tile_width > grid_width) return true;
                if (tile_height > grid_height) return true;

                var count_horizontal = ~~(grid_width / tile_width);
                var count_vertical = ~~(grid_height / tile_height);
                if (count_horizontal * count_vertical < tiles) return true;

                result.push([
                    tile_width, tile_height,
                    count_horizontal, count_vertical
                ]);
            });
        if (result.length > 1) return result;
    }
    return null;
}

function divisors_do(x, f)
{
    var history = [1];
    if (f(1) === false) return false;

    // for each prime factor
    return prime_factors_do(x,
        function(prime, primePower)
        {
            var len = history.length;

            for (var iHistory = 0; iHistory < len; iHistory++)
            {
                var divisor = history[iHistory];

                for (var power = 1; power <= primePower; power++)
                {
                    divisor *= prime;
                    history.push(divisor);

                    if (f(divisor) === false) return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        });
}

function prime_factors_do(x, f)
{
    for (var test = 2; test*test <= x; test++)
    {
        var power = 0;
        while ((x % test) == 0)
        {
            power++;
            x /= test;
        }

        // If we found a prime factor, report it, and
        // abort if `f` returns false.
        if (power > 0 && f(test, power) === false)
            return false;
    }

    if (x > 1) return f(x,1);
    return true;
}
```

Example:

```
> pack(5, 12, 8);
[16, [2, 8, 6, 1], [4, 4, 3, 2]]
> pack(47,1024,768);
[16384, [64, 256, 16, 3], [128, 128, 8, 6], [256, 64, 4, 12], [512, 32, 2, 24]]
```

The first example produces two equivalent results:

- 2x8 tiles packed in one row of 6
- 4x4 tiles packed in two rows of 3

In each case, one slot is left unused, leaving a total of 16 cells unused.

```
### ### ### ### ### . .    ####### ####### #######
### ### ### ### ###        ####### ####### #######
### ### ### ### ### . .    ####### ####### #######
### ### ### ### ###        ####### ####### #######
### ### ### ### ### . .    ####### ####### #######
### ### ### ### ###        ####### ####### #######
### ### ### ### ### . .    ####### ####### #######
### ### ### ### ###
### ### ### ### ### . .    ####### ####### .  .  .
### ### ### ### ###        ####### ####### 
### ### ### ### ### . .    ####### ####### .  .  .
### ### ### ### ###        ####### ####### 
### ### ### ### ### . .    ####### ####### .  .  .
### ### ### ### ###        ####### ####### 
### ### ### ### ### . .    ####### ####### .  .  .
```

Comment: I rewrote it using factorization. It now tries smaller and smaller area, until it gets a result. Now it's much faster, but I don't know if it's complexity got any better.