# Figuring ratio of ranges against a fixed number

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, algorithm

I have a dynamic range of X by Y sheet sizes which need to be tested by a long running algorithm.

For example, I am going to try any sheet size between 40-50 inches wide by 40-80 inches long. It would take too long to try every integer combination so I want to limit the iterations to 30.

Since there are only 10 units in the X range and 40 units in the Y range, I need to test about 3 X units and 10 Y units and skip the rest.

How can this be coded to figure out the *closest ratio and end up with only 30 iterations*? It needs to be dynamic because these ranges keep changing and *sometimes the Y range is less than the X range*.

answer: (inspired by Fraser)

```
Dim ratioX As Integer = txtSizeFormSingleXmax - txtSizeFormSingleXmin
Dim ratioY As Integer = txtSizeFormSingleYmax - txtSizeFormSingleYmin
Dim FinalRatioNumerator As Integer
Dim FinalRatioDenominator As Integer
Dim XGreaterThanY As Boolean = False

If ratioX > ratioY Then
   Dim tempRatio As Integer
   tempRatio = ratioY
   ratioY = ratioX
   ratioX = tempRatio
   XGreaterThanY = True
End If
For countRatio As Integer = 1 To 30
   If ratioX / ratioY <= countRatio / CInt(30 / countRatio) Then
      FinalRatioNumerator = countRatio
      FinalRatioDenominator = CInt(30 / countRatio)
      Exit For
   End If
Next
```

Comment: This looks more like a math question...

Comment: @HanletEscaño or [**Programmers**](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This probably belongs at [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Although not the same there are similarities to a question I answered some time back: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3513565/338068 . Similar principles can be used. If your maths is up to it you might be able to use these same principles. Unfortunately I don't have the time to work out a full solution for this problem at the moment.

Comment: @TLS: I wouldn't say it was a math problem really. Its an algorithm issue really (I've added the algorithm tag to try to attract that crowd).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since # of iterations must be whole numbers our options are 1,30 2,15 3,10 and 5,6 you may want to consider 4,7 or 4,8 though 30 iterations is not met.

if i pseudo this up without optimization so its easier to follow my logic

```
get ranges x and y

if x>y y/x = ratio else swap x and y
```

now all you really need to do (given you are set on 30 ish iterations)

```
calc difference in ratio
for each pair possible
(((x/y)-(1/30 ))^2)^(1/2) =result

now you just take the closest match (smallest result) and use those 
as your test numbers

for each xtestval in mylist of xtestvals
(Xrange  / xTestNum) + xrange min = xtestval
mylist.add(xtestval)
xrange min = xtestval
next
```

then you have your test values for each axis so you double loop to get the combinations

```
for each x
    for each y
        pair x and y
    next
next
```

not super clear but hopefully clear enough... back to work for me!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to rephrase your question, is this decription correct? Given a taret ratio:

`W / H`

You want to optimize `X / Y` as close to `W / H` as possible, while `xmin < x < xmax` and `ymin < y < ymax`.

Proposed algorithm:

```
var x = xmin + xmax / 2;
var y = ymin + ymax / 2;
function int[] adjustRange(x, y, wHRatio)
{
    var curRatio = x / y;
    if(curRatio == wHRatio)
    {
        return [x, y];
    }
    else if(curRatio < wHRatio)
    {
        // you want to increase x or decrease y. If neither are possible, x/y
        //      is as close as you will get. You can fudge your intervals to be
        //      based on the xmax-xmin and ymax-ymin, or some number from a 
        //      config file
    }
    else if(curRatio > wHRatio)
    {
        // you want to decrease x or increase y. If neither are possible, x/y
        //      is as close as you will get
    }
}
```